# visual studio 2019 enter on intellisense creates newline

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In VS 2019 when intellisense comes up and I select an option by pressing enter a new line is created and I have to constantly backspace to get back to the line I was just on. This is a change from all previous VS versions. I changed the option (Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> Intellisense -> Enter key behavior -> to "Never add a new line on enter" but its still adding a new line.

How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just to cover bases: Do you have the latest VS 2019 version installed? If not, which version are you running?

Comment: I've got the latest version. 16.6.0 updated to four days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> Formatting-> New Lines

Here there are a lot of options. Remove the check on all options here to never put the open bracket on a new line.